# What are the possible values that can happen in a INT column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm making a etl and I will use MYSQL for storing time series data. I have a lot of int columns and I want to know if there is any kind of NaN like in pandas that can happen or its only possible values like 0,1,2,3 and NULL.

I tried to search on google but didnt find anything
Thanks

Comment: NaN in pandas is effectively NULL in MySQL. They both have toolkit functions to operate specifically with them, with respect to their environment, whether it's Python or MySQL.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+int+data+type will likely show you MySQL documentation link first. You can check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html directly.

Comment: Integers generally have a numerical range limit, and can be `NULL` if allowed by the schema. Otherwise there's nothing weird like IEEE NaN or negative zero going on.

Comment: You may want to check out the out-of-range handling that MySQL does: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Comment: Besides those you listed, `INT` also supports negative values. :-)